# rewrite expression in another form

Tags: conic-sections

I'm studying applied electromagnetism and in the book I'm following there is this passage I'm having a hard time trying to reproduce:

[image]

I feel a little silly asking this type of question, however I'm stuck in this for at least 40 minutes.

Comment: $1=\sin^2(\omega t)+\cos^2(\omega t)$

Comment: The last equation is $$ \Big( - \sin(\omega t) \Big)^2 + \cos^2(\omega t) = \sin^2(\omega t) + \cos^2(\omega t) = 1$$

Comment: So actually there is no substitution in 5-45b, right?